# Nginx FastCGI not caching static files?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, static-files

I configure fastCGI to cache with NginX. It work with .php file, but i can't cache static file like .jpg, .mp4...

My infomation when check with cURL:

```
curl -I http://192.168.1.223/music.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2015 20:21:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
X-Cache: HIT

curl -I http://192.168.1.223/b2.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2015 20:24:51 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 18103
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Dec 2015 20:06:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5665e6c3-46b7"
Expires: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 20:24:51 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=5184000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

My NginX config:

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 1;
lock_file /run/lock/nginx.lock;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        application pullfromwowza {
           live on;
           pull rtmp://192.168.1.222:1935/vod;
        }
     }
}

http {
    server_tokens off;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    #include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #gzip on;
    #gzip_static on;
    #gzip_comp_level 2;
    #gzip_disable "msie6";
    #gzip_proxied any;
    #gzip_types application/javascript application/json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml #text/css text/plain text/xml;
    #gzip_vary on;

    fastcgi_cache_path /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=fastcgicache:200m inactive=200m max_size=640m;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;
    # note: can also use HTTP headers to form the cache key, e.g.
    #fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$http_x_custom_header;
    fastcgi_cache_lock on;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 5m;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

    index index.php;


    server {
        listen   80;

        server_name example.com;


 root /usr/local/nginx/html;
        #root /var/www/example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        # example FastCGI cache exception rules
        set $fastcgi_skipcache 0;

        if ($query_string) {
            set $fastcgi_skipcache 1;
        }

    if ($http_x_custom_header) {
            set $fastcgi_skipcache 0;
        }

        if ($uri ~ "/path/matches/") {
            set $fastcgi_skipcache 1;
        }

        if ($http_cookie ~ "users_login_cookie") {
            set $fastcgi_skipcache 1;
        }

        #include /etc/nginx/conf/phpfastcgicache;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ "\.php$" {
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name)
            {
                return 404;
            }
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            # note: adds a HTTP response header "X-Cache" returning HIT/MISS/BYPASS/EXPIRED for cache use status
            add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            fastcgi_cache fastcgicache;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $fastcgi_skipcache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $fastcgi_skipcache;

            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
  expires -1;
  # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
}

# Feed
location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
  expires 1h;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz) {
            expires 60d;

           # proxy_pass http://192.168.11.11:8888;
           # proxy_redirect     off;

            #proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            fastcgi_cache fastcgicache;
           # proxy_cache_key "$request_method|$host|$request_uri";
           # proxy_cache_valid 1d;
      }

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to cache a static file!

Comment: I thinks this line make cache static file? location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz)

Comment: This lines (actually `expires 60d;` line) tells browser to cache file for 60 days. It has nothing to do with nginx's cache. And there in no point to cache static files. They are already "_cached_" on you disk.

Comment: How I make cache a static file. I don't think: "They are already "cached" on you disk. " Because i checked in cache folder (/data/nginx/cache) it don't have any thing :(

Comment: Oh. There is no need to put static file in cache. They are already on disk and there is no reason to put them into some other place on disk.

Comment: but another static source still no cache :( ex: My NginX server is 192.168.1.223 and i'm insert .jpeg link from ip 192.168.1.224 into .php file.

Comment: i need NginX to cache static file from another site, can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complete other answers.

Saying the a file is already cached because it's on disk is not a satisfactory answer. For exemple, Apache2 is very slow at serving static files that are on disk, thus a proxy cache as nginx or varnish totally makes sense for a high trafic website.

In nginx case, it is designed to be very efficient to serve static content.

But you should ensure you have "sendfile on" enabled (it is the case in your configuration).
Senfile() replace the classe couple read()/write() at kernel level and makes the files access very quick.

The quickness is high enough to be as performant as if the content was cached.

By the way I recommand you to enable tcp_nodelay as well. It allows nginx to send a short TCP packet immediately if there is no other data expected.

See also:

- sendfile() man: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html
- sendfile, tcp_nodelay and tcp_nopush directives: https://t37.net/nginx-optimization-understanding-sendfile-tcp_nodelay-and-tcp_nopush.html

Comment: These belong in `nginx.conf` in case anyone is wondering e.g. `sendfile on; tcp_nopush on; tcp_nodelay on;`

Answer (score 0):

You're not serving static files from a cache, because you've not configured any caching for static files.  Unless your PHP script is serving that `b2.jpg`, in which case you've got larger problems.

Comment: I am new bie on NginX, pls show me more :(

Comment: i need NginX to cache static file from another site, can you help me?

Comment: If you ask a new question, which is appropriate for this site, I (or someone else) will answer it.  Otherwise, I don't do independent consulting any more.

Comment: Thanks you ! I posted new question at here: http://serverfault.com/questions/743061/how-nginx-cache-static-file-from-another-site?noredirect=1#comment929930_743061

Answer (score 0):

This question is underrated, and not communicated well enough in the Nginx (or web server) community, because everyone copy and pastes tutorials!

The comments on OP post are true enough, but @Daneel has an excellent answer that addresses something deeper in the stack -- beyond Nginx, how the operating system and hardware respond.

And really, that is more relevant for serving static files. After all, Nginx can only "serve" files on disk as fast as the OS, kernel, virtual system, and hardware allow it to do so...

What so many tutorials forget to mention is that optimizing your Nginx settings is not enough, for top notch performance (esp. for VPS/VM/cloud servers) you also should optimize your kernel. If anyone is interested you can check the [systctl.conf](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/modules/ubuntu/sysctl.txt) we use in SlickStack (a LEMP script for WordPress).

Also another relevant feature to note is `TMPFS` which is a method of leverage your RAM memory as much as possible to avoid disk I/O... if you're looking for extreme optimization of Nginx and static files then it becomes more important to find a high-quality datacenter with great hardware (KVM virtualization, NVMe SSD drives, great OS/package management), and then get a machine with plenty of RAM so that your system can help Nginx as much as possible to deliver files quickly.

And if you're going to use Nginx FastCGI cache along with `TMPFS` (serving files from RAM) then be sure you have tons of available RAM, and know the potential risks before activating, which can include data loss in case of sudden server crashes or hard restarts, and so forth...